# How do you pass semantic data do a jQuery delegate?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Delegation/"on" in jQuery seems to be the new hotness. And I totally get that the delegate function receives the event object.

But my question is how do I pass semantic/application data to the delegate?

### Old way, without delegation:

```
// bind a new closure for each button
for (var i = 0; i < MyApp.Widgets.length; i++) {
  var widgetId = MyApp.Widgets[i];

  $('#myapp-widget-button-' + i).click(
    function () {
      MyApp.upgradeWidgetById(widgetId);
    }
  );
}
```

### New way, with delegation (and parts missing):

```
// refactor custom closures into one delegate
$('#myapp-widget-container').delegate('.myapp-widget-button', 'click', function () {
  // MyApp.upgradeWidgetById( ... )
});
```

Where does the `widgetId` come from? I'm sensing that this is where data attributes come into play:

### New way, with delegation and data attributes

```
// attach application data to the handled objects
for (var i = 0; i < MyApp.Widgets.length; i++) {
  var widgetId = MyApp.Widgets[i];

  $('#myapp-widget-button-' + i).data('widgetId', widgetId);
}

// refactor custom closures into one delegate
$('#myapp-widget-container').delegate('.myapp-widget-button', 'click', function () {
  var widgetId = $(this).data('widgetId');

  MyApp.upgradeWidgetById(widgetId)
});
```

But is that really the only way? I'm concerned because not many tutorials mention data attributes in relation to delegates so I'm wondering if I'm missing something or doing something wrong.

Edit: Edited to reflect that "on" is the new black, despite being a delegate in sheep's clothing.

Comment: It is not new hotness. _As of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation. More information on event binding and delegation is in the `.on()` method._

Comment: @Vega, [actually, the wording ***superseded*** is well used there](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.fn.delegate).

Comment: In your case it may make more sense to not use delegation if you already have to loop through them to associate data. You mightaswell just bind the event while you're there and keep it simple.

Comment: I stand corrected on the hotness comment. Thanks @Vega. I'm like stuck in prehistoric jQuery.

Comment: @MarkCanlas You don't really need delegate if you could set data attr on those element. Just use `.click`. Delegation's are simply slower and consumes lot of resource when compared to direct binding.

Comment: So if we use data attributes, we can assign the same click handler directly to each button? I.e. not incur the overhead of multiple different closures? And also, are data attributes the only way? Or is there some other pattern/method?

Comment: @MarkCanlas Check my answer and see if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need delegation since you seem to set the data attribute for those elements.

Just use `.click` like below with data args,

```
// attach application data to the handled objects
for (var i = 0; i < MyApp.Widgets.length; i++) {
  var widgetId = MyApp.Widgets[i];

  $('#myapp-widget-button-' + i).click({'widgetId', widgetId}, myFunction);
}

//later in code
function myFunction(e) {
    var widgetId = e.data.widgetId;

    //your code
}
```

**Note:** I am using `.click` as I am not sure of the version of jQuery you are using.

Comment: The question isn't really about delegation vs direct click handlers as it is questioning if data attributes are the only way to shuttle data into the delegate function.

Comment: @MarkCanlas And the answer explains you that you can pass a data arg which allows you to pass the `widgetID` to the handler function. Check the first argument to the `.click` function.

Comment: Ahh I missed that part. Thanks!